Clipping constraints
I will be going ahead and adjusting my clip start and end values as I believe they are quite important to preserving RAM/CPU usage. One thing I am not sure of is if I was to export this project to Godot 4 will this clip start and end information be exported as well so the RAM/CPU usage preservation can persist in the game engine itself?

